# JPA how to lazily load collection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

Please advise how to lazily load the map "Groupunit_from"? How to open a JPA session and transaction?

```
 @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name="place_definer_groupunit_from",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="groupunit_from"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name="id")
    @MapKeyClass(String.class)
    @Column(name="ordinal",nullable=false)
    private Map<String,String> Groupunit_from=new HashMap<>();//
```

Answer (score 2):

Collections are loaded Lazily by *default*.

You don't have to specify anything to load a collection lazily.

**To initialize a session and Transaction in JPA**

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistentUnitName");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

// to begin a transaction
em.getTransaction().begin();

// here you can flush or persist

// to commit a transaction
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: thank you  sir, I understand that I have firstly to create the "persistence.xml" file, by using springboot, where I have to put this file?

Comment: You say "You don't have to specify anything to load a collection lazily.", I use JPA findOne/findAll to retrieve the entity,but when I perform "getGroupunit_from", there is error message "no session".

Answer (score 0):

you already mentioned "fetch=FetchType.LAZY" so jpa will load this elements lazily. If you observe the queries fired in the application while debugging, you will observe that the queries for populating this map will be fired when you use this map for the first time in your java code.

Comment: I see, I use JPA findOne/findAll to retrieve the entity, but when I perform "getGroupunit_from", there is error message "no session".